# What is the line between a "pro webmaster" question and a...well, not "pro webmaster" question?

Tags: discussion, suitable-question, questions

For example, I own a domain name and I'm working on getting content. But I'm trying to choose between building and deploying custom software (I'm a software engineer by education), what off-the-shelf software is appropriate (and trying to find more options given a few samples of software that are close to what I want), and best practices for running a personal website (and by best practices, I mean specific question on if I should do X as opposed to Y or if X would have some benefit).

Are questions that I might have on these topics be suitable here? I'm by no means a professional webmaster, but I would like to maintain my own web presence. It seems like this site might be a closer fit to my needs than Super User, but I'm not entirely sure which of my questions are in scope and which ones aren't.

Thanks!

Comment: +1, I'll add myself to the list of those confused. I've seen several comments along "That's not for this site, go to x" on Pro Webmasters. Honestly, I now don't understand what content *is* supposed to be on Pro Webmasters.

Comment: Similarly: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/298/is-the-name-webmasters-the-right-name-for-this-site

Comment: can you propose some example questions rather than just saying "I'm not entirely sure which of my questions are in scope?"

Answer (score 3):

Another problem, speaking as a regular on another Stack Overflow website, is that questions are posted on other SO websites that perhaps belong here and it is (imo) unclear what should be migrated.

Should a question from Server Fault be migrated the moment it mentions configuring apache? Should questions about cpanel be migrated here? Should a question from SO be migrated the moment it mentions php?

I don't want to migrate questions here if I shouldn't, but it's reasonably clear if a developer asks about setting up a server for dev purposes that that question belongs on SF. It's clear that if someone asks on SF about code samples for doing something in SQL server that the question probably belongs on SO. If a question on either of those two sites asks about connecting their laptop to their PS3 or XBOX360 at home then its very clear that they need to be on Super User.

But the delineation between questions that belong here vs. belonging on SO or SF is much less clear.

Comment: Apache and config stuff in my opinion belongs on SF, as in this day and age the configuration for everything (caching, rewriting, etc) is beyond the field of "webmaster", as in my experience webmasters only know what they learn about config from copy/pasting stuff from tutorials on the web.

Comment: I can see your point but I think this demonstrates the difficulty of deciding what should be on which site. So what questions on SF that I see should be migrated to pro webmasters? If it can't be clearly defined (I know there are always going to be edge cases, not talking about those) then it isn't going end well imho.

Answer (score 2):

We're still trying to figure that out :)  I think that if you go along and ask specific questions with a specific goal in mind, the majority of your questions will probably be on-topic.

Comment: Is the ongoing discussion actually happening someplace visible? If it isn't, it should be. If it is, could you throw me a link since I didn't see it here on Meta.

Comment: The ongoing discussion happens primarily on the main website when people hit the close or reopen button and add comments justifying their votes.

Comment: @Thomas Owens it's spread out between the questions on the main site, and lots of case-specific topics here on meta.

Comment: OK, cool. I'll just ask my questions and see what happens then. Thanks.

Comment: if you put domain questions on server fault, and seo questions on doctype (or the new html/css stackexchange 2.0 proposal), what would we have left? I think we need to open up to include html/css and become a web-qa site, and i've said as much here too: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22803/web-design

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that our current site title is just the phrase that was used when our site was proposed on Area51. We've evolved a bit beyond the question examples there, but the topic remains the same. From [our FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Pro Webmasters - Stack Exchange is for
>   professional and enthusiast
>   webmasters. If your question generally
>   covers the operation of websites which
>   you control, then you're in the right
>   place to ask your question!

A professional is someone who gets paid to do something that they (might) be good at doing. There are lots of programmers on Stack Overflow, but not all of them are professional - many are just trying to learn something in their spare time.

You would most decidedly fall into the "Enthusiast" category. As long as your questions are on topic, they would of course be more than welcome.

Our final name / domain name will very likely be 'professionally' agnostic. While some SE sites do limit beginner questions, we aren't one of them.